# Why PyList_Append is called each time a list is evaluated?

Tags: python, c, gdb, cpython, python-internals

I'm working with `CPython3.11.0a3+`. I added a break point at [`PyList_Append`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0a3/Objects/listobject.c#L324) and modified the function to stop when the `newitem` is a `dict`. The original function:

```c
int
PyList_Append(PyObject *op, PyObject *newitem)
{
    if (PyList_Check(op) && (newitem != NULL))
        return app1((PyListObject *)op, newitem);
    PyErr_BadInternalCall();
    return -1;
}
```

Modified version:

```c
int
PyList_Append(PyObject *op, PyObject *newitem)
{
    if (PyDict_CheckExact(newitem)) {
        fprintf(stdout, "hello\n");
    }
    if (PyList_Check(op) && (newitem != NULL))
        return app1((PyListObject *)op, newitem);
    PyErr_BadInternalCall();
    return -1;
}
```

I placed a break point on line `fprintf(stdout, "hello\n");`. This is because in python startup process, there are infinite calls of `PyList_Append` but none of them are with `newitem` of type `dict`. So in this way I can escape all of those calls and reach the `repl` to workaround with my own variables.

```
(gdb) break Objects/listobject.c:328
Breakpoint 1 at 0x44fb00: file Objects/listobject.c, line 328.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/amirreza/Desktop/edu/python_internals/1/cpython/python 
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.31-2.fc32.x86_64
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Python 3.11.0a3+ (heads/main-dirty:1cbb887, Dec  1 2022, 12:22:29) [GCC 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(3)
>>> a
[3]
>>> a.append({})
>>> 
>>> a

Breakpoint 1, PyList_Append (op=op@entry=0x7fffea8e9780, newitem=newitem@entry=0x7fffeaa22bc0) at Objects/listobject.c:328
328         fprintf(stdout, "hello\n");
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install ncurses-libs-6.1-15.20191109.fc32.x86_64 readline-8.0-4.fc32.x86_64
(gdb) c
Continuing.
hello
[3, {}]
>>> 
>>> a

Breakpoint 1, PyList_Append (op=op@entry=0x7fffea8e9780, newitem=newitem@entry=0x7fffeaa22bc0) at Objects/listobject.c:328
328         fprintf(stdout, "hello\n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
hello
[3, {}]
>>> 
>>> a

Breakpoint 1, PyList_Append (op=op@entry=0x7fffea8e9780, newitem=newitem@entry=0x7fffeaa22bc0) at Objects/listobject.c:328
328         fprintf(stdout, "hello\n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
hello
[3, {}]
>>>
```

My question is why each time I only try to evaluate the `a` list, the `PyList_Append` is invoked? For the first time we can ignore it due to lazy-evaluation. But for the second and third time, why it's called every time?

Comment: 3.11.0 is out. Why are you using an alpha release?

Comment: @user2357112 I just had this version from long ago. I didn't pulled the new changes.

Comment: Also, there's no lazy evaluation here. If you're wondering why `a.append({})` doesn't trigger the breakpoint, it's because that goes through [`list_append`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0a3/Objects/listobject.c#L848), not `PyList_Append`.

Comment: @user2357112 So would you tell me what is the `PyList_Append`? and what's the difference between `list_append`?

Comment: `PyList_Append` is the C API function for appending to lists. `list_append` is the implementation of the `list.append` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dict.__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0a3/Objects/dictobject.c#L2050) uses the CPython-internal `Py_ReprEnter` and `Py_ReprLeave` functions to stop infinite recursion for recursively nested data structures, and `Py_ReprEnter` [appends](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/74d5f61ebd1cb14907bf7dae1ad9c1e676707bc5/Objects/object.c#L2169) the dict to a list of objects currently having their `repr` evaluated in the running thread.

Comment: Thanks! I understood, So in my case it has nothing to do with the `a` list, If I simply try to print a `dict` the `PyList_Append` will be invoked.

Comment: I know it's a little bit off-topic, but how can I learn more about cpython internals? I've searched and have found some good resources, but do you suggest anything too?